# Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, https, influxdb

I have a python application running on a virtual machine, were a legacy, and now I'm migrating to a Kubernetes.

I use `influxdb==5.2.3` package, connecting to this form `Influx(host=r'influx_HOST', port=8086, username='MY_USER', password='***', database='DB_NAME', ssl=True)`. This python script calls an InfluxBD using an SSL certificate and when I run directly using `python app.py` works well, but, the problem is when:

#### I dockerized the script shows me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 591, in <module>
    get_horas_stock()
  File "app.py", line 513, in get_horas_stock
    df_temp = influx_temperatura.multiple_query_to_df(queries_temperatura)
  File "/usr/src/app/analitica_py_lib_conexiones/conexion_influx.py", line 82, in multiple_query_to_df
    resultado = self.__cliente.query(";".join(queries))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 445, in query
    response = self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 302, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
```

I understand to, from inside the container, the script is using https to call Influx, but I think the connection is redirected outside the container using Http and lose all SSL configuration, why? I don't know.

#### I tested deployed on Kubernetes

I tried to deploy on Kubernetes thinking I get the same error, but it`s changed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 360, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 442, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 454, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 498, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 750, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 494, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 459, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 378, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 591, in <module>
    get_horas_stock()
  File "app.py", line 513, in get_horas_stock
    df_temp = influx_temperatura.multiple_query_to_df(queries_temperatura)
  File "/usr/src/app/analitica_py_lib_conexiones/conexion_influx.py", line 82, in multiple_query_to_df
    resultado = self.__cliente.query(";".join(queries))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 445, in query
    response = self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 274, in request
    response = self._session.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 686, in send
    r.content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 828, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 753, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I don't know if is related to the previous error.

[image]

#### Edited

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.2-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Kubernetes Deployment YML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-ms
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      ip-service: my-ms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        ip-service: my-ms
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-ms
          image: myprivate.azurecr.io/my-ms:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 10Mi
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: tecnoregistry
```

#### Edited 2

I get the same error I have on Kubernetes, but running the script locally, I change the SSL value from True to False in the service call `Influx(host=r'influx_HOST', port=8086, username='MY_USER', password='***', database='DB_NAME', ssl=False)`.

```
~$ python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 360, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 442, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 457, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 501, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 750, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 494, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 459, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 378, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1272, in <module>
    generate_excels_consumo()
  File "/Volumes/DATA/IdeaProjects/australia/analitica_py_sw_recolect_info/calculo_excels.py", line 206, in generate_excels_consumo
    df_sector = influx_kpis.multiple_query_to_multiple_df(queries)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/IdeaProjects/australia/analitica_py_sw_recolect_info/analitica_py_lib_conexiones/conexion_influx.py", line 126, in multiple_query_to_multiple_df
    resultado = self.__cliente.query(";".join(query))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 450, in query
    expected_response_code=expected_response_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 283, in request
    timeout=self._timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 686, in send
    r.content
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 828, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 753, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: No idea what this is all about, but I'll give you a +1 for the drawing. Pure dedication.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a network problem. I faced a similar problem connecting with MongoDB because of Proxy.

By default, each container run by Docker has its own network namespace.

Offering Some Solution Methods:

1. `traceroute <cluster-ip>` perform this command and check whether arrive to cluster inside of container attach container and perform the command `docker exec -it container /bin/bash`.
2. Check Proxy. `export` check environment variables related with proxy.
3. `curl www.google.com`
4. Try to connect another things in the cluster. For example MySQL, etc. (Once time a machine write me blacklist automatically I tried to solve connection problem 2 day)
5. Try to use python-slim image. slim image is based from ubuntu.

It is very good document to understand and solve docker connection problem.

https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/