# Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server - Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, https

I have created a Kubernetes cluster in the [cloud- using this tutorial](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/deploy-kubernetes-using-kubespray/) and deployed [to the cluster] a backend application called `chatapp` from the Docker private registry. Since there is no option to include service type as `LoadBalancer`, I had to restore to `NodePort` type.
Here is the `chatapp-deployment.yml` file for reference:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: chatapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: chatapp
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 6443
    targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort
  externalIPs:
  - A.B.C.D

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chatapp
  labels:
    app: chatapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chatapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chatapp
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
      containers:
      - name: chatapp
        image: sebastian/chatapp
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
```

**Note:** I removed the external IP for security reasons.

I had to assign external IP manually since I couldn't set-up `LoadBalancer` as service type. Whenever I try accessing `http://A.B.C.D:6443`, I get the following:

```
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
```

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017106/client-sent-an-http-request-to-an-https-server) but couldn't fix my issue with it. The external IP I have used is from the `master-o`.

While trying to access it with https://A.B.C.D:6443, I get the following `403` message:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
```

How can I authorize access to my cluster? Any feedbacks and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That a.b.c.d:6443 you've mentioned in the **kubernetes** API, and is wholly separate from Services on your cluster. That's why `NodePort` type Services exist, to map external ports down onto in-cluster ports. This question is a networking misconfiguration and thus off topic for a programming site

Answer (score 1):

Your request has reached the k8s api-server at 6443 instead of your chatapp. To access your chatapp; first retrieve the nodePort number: `kubectl describe service chatapp | grep -i nodeport`, then use this # to access your app at `http://a.b.c.d:<nodePort>`